# Firebase text and image upload crashes app

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Application I'm developing is crashing when I click a button. The button is supposed to upload picture and text to `firebase`. Here is the code I get the error on:

```
public class ProfileUtils {

    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private StorageReference storageReference;
    private Map<String, String> userSetupMap;
    private ProcessStatusObservable processStatusObservable;
    private StorageReference imgPath;
    private String userId;


    public ProfileUtils(){
         processStatusObservable = new ProcessStatusObservable();
         userSetupMap = new HashMap<>();
         firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
         userId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
         storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    }
    private void uploadPicture(String pictureType, Uri uri, StorageReference storageReference){

        imgPath.putFile(uri).addOnCompleteListener(task -> { //I GET ERROR HERE//
            if(task.isSuccessful()){

                    Uri imageUri = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl();
                    userSetupMap.put(pictureType.concat("PictureUrl"), imageUri.toString());

            }
            else{

            }
        });
    }
    public ProfileUtils setProfilePicture(Uri uri){
        storageReference = storageReference.child("Profile pictures").child(userId+".jpg");
        uploadPicture("profile", uri, storageReference);
        return this;
    }
    public ProfileUtils setCoverPicture(Uri uri){
        StorageReference coverPath = storageReference.child("Cover pictures").child(userId+".jpg");
        uploadPicture("cover", uri, coverPath);
        return this;
    }
    public ProfileUtils setUserName(String userName){
        userSetupMap.put("name", userName);
        return this;
    }

    public void commit(){
        firebaseFirestore.collection("Users").document(userId)
            .set(userSetupMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    processStatusObservable.setStatus(ProcessStatus.NEW_USER_PROFILE_SETUP_SUCCESS);
                }
                else{

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Error Logcat:

```
05-18 21:11:09.486 15873-15873/com.sachintitus.instafy.instafy D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-18 21:11:09.487 15873-15972/com.sachintitus.instafy.instafy W/common.FileUtils: Failed to set dir world executable: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/files/gmscore_global_dirs.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
05-18 21:11:09.488 15873-15873/com.sachintitus.instafy.instafy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sachintitus.instafy.instafy, PID: 15873
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(android.net.Uri)' on a null object reference
        at com.sachintitus.instafy.instafy.repository.Model.Factories.FirebaseUtils.ProfileUtils.uploadPicture(ProfileUtils.java:46)
        at com.sachintitus.instafy.instafy.repository.Model.Factories.FirebaseUtils.ProfileUtils.setProfilePicture(ProfileUtils.java:60)
        at com.sachintitus.instafy.instafy.repository.Model.Factories.FireStore.setUpNewUser(FireStore.java:63)
        at com.sachintitus.instafy.instafy.repository.Repository.setUpNewUser(Repository.java:58)
        at com.sachintitus.instafy.instafy.viewmodel.BioSetupActivityViewModel.setupNewUser(BioSetupActivityViewModel.java:11)
        at presenter.BioSetupActivityPresenter.setUpBasicProfile(BioSetupActivityPresenter.java:65)
        at com.sachintitus.instafy.instafy.view.BioSetupActivity.lambda$onCreate$1$BioSetupActivity(BioSetupActivity.java:77)
        at com.sachintitus.instafy.instafy.view.BioSetupActivity$$Lambda$1.onClick(Unknown Source:21)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:12470)
        at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:7475)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2715)
        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:11713)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1834)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1819)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:3267)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:534)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:58)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:316)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:354)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4733)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4605)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4293)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4350)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4174)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4147)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4326)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4487)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2435)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1998)
05-18 21:11:09.489 15873-15873/com.sachintitus.instafy.instafy E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1989)
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2412)
        at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logs already gave you the answer.

It is obvious that your imgPath is null because it was never initialized.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask
>   com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(android.net.Uri)'
>   on a null object reference at
>   com.sachintitus.instafy.instafy.repository.Model.Factories.FirebaseUtils.ProfileUtils.uploadPicture(ProfileUtils.java:46)